# I want to calculate total sales

Tags: javascript, json

This is my data and I'd like to calculate total sales.

```
 let order = [
    { id: 'A441', sales: [10, 12, 13, 10, 16, 22, 30] },
    { id: 'B234', sales: [2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 6, 8, 10] },
    { id: 'A617', sales: [5, 5, 5, 5, 5] },
    { id: 'C229', sales: [9, 7, 6, 8, 8, 10, 9, 3, 4, 5, 6] },
    { id: 'D412', sales: [25, 25, 23, 21] },
    { id: 'A054', sales: [2, 2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 7, 11, 2] },
    { id: 'B955', sales: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] },
    { id: 'M341', sales: [4, 5, 4, 5, 4] },
    { id: 'H103', sales: [3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1] },
    { id: 'B199', sales: [6, 5, 4] },
    { id: 'D388', sales: [7, 8, 9, 8, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1] }
];
```

Comment: please add the result and your try. and add a little formating to the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the total by sale type:

```js
let orders = [ 
  { id: 'A441', sales: [10, 12, 13, 10, 16, 22, 30] },
  { id: 'B234', sales: [2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 6, 8, 10] }, 
  { id: 'A617', sales: [5, 5, 5, 5, 5] }, 
  { id: 'C229', sales: [9, 7, 6, 8, 8, 10, 9, 3, 4, 5, 6] }, 
  { id: 'D412', sales: [25, 25, 23, 21] }, 
  { id: 'A054', sales: [2, 2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 7, 11, 2] }, 
  { id: 'B955', sales: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] }, 
  { id: 'M341', sales: [4, 5, 4, 5, 4] }, 
  { id: 'H103', sales: [3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1] },
  { id: 'B199', sales: [6, 5, 4] }, 
  { id: 'D388', sales: [7, 8, 9, 8, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1] } 
];

function getTotalSales(orders){
  return orders.map(order=> ({...order, totalSales: order.sales.reduce((acc, cur)=> acc+=cur, 0)}))
}

console.log(getTotalSales(orders))
```

If you want the total of all sales:

```js
let orders = [ 
  { id: 'A441', sales: [10, 12, 13, 10, 16, 22, 30] },
  { id: 'B234', sales: [2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 6, 8, 10] }, 
  { id: 'A617', sales: [5, 5, 5, 5, 5] }, 
  { id: 'C229', sales: [9, 7, 6, 8, 8, 10, 9, 3, 4, 5, 6] }, 
  { id: 'D412', sales: [25, 25, 23, 21] }, 
  { id: 'A054', sales: [2, 2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 7, 11, 2] }, 
  { id: 'B955', sales: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] }, 
  { id: 'M341', sales: [4, 5, 4, 5, 4] }, 
  { id: 'H103', sales: [3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1] },
  { id: 'B199', sales: [6, 5, 4] }, 
  { id: 'D388', sales: [7, 8, 9, 8, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1] } 
];

function getTotalSales(orders){
  return orders.map(({sales})=> sales).flat().reduce((acc, cur)=> acc+=cur, 0)
}

console.log(getTotalSales(orders))
```